# Number of registers per thread

Tags: cuda

Is there any advantage to keeping the registers/thread count low for a CUDA kenel?

I'm thinking there is no advantage (speed or otherwise).  A context switch is as fast for 3 reg's/thread, as it is for 48 regs/thread.  And there is no point in not using all available registers, unless you just don't want to.  Registers are not shared between kernels.
Is this wrong?

**Edit:**
From CUDA4.2 programming guide (5.2.3):

```
    The number of registers used by a kernel can have a significant impact on the number 
    of resident warps. For example, for devices of compute capability 1.2, if a kernel uses 16 
registers and each block has 512 threads and requires very little shared memory, then two 
    blocks (i.e. 32 warps) can reside on the multiprocessor since they require 2x512x16 
    registers, which exactly matches the number of registers available on the multiprocessor.
     But as soon as the kernel uses one more register, only one block (i.e. 16 warps) can be 
    resident since two blocks would require 2x512x17 registers, which are more registers than 
    are available on the multiprocessor. Therefore, the compiler attempts to minimize register 
    usage while keeping register spilling (see Section 5.3.2.2) and the number of instructions 
    to a minimum.
```

The "regs/thread" count doesn't appear to matter as much as the total reg count.

Answer (score 3):

The number of registers in use affects the occupancy of your GPU since the total number of registers per multiprocessor is limited.

See the [CUDA Occupancy calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls)

You can input your compute capability, shared memory size configuration value, the number of threads per block, registers per thread and the number of shared memory bytes per block.

The sheet will give you informations on how many threads will run per multiprocessor (mp), how many warps are active, the number of thread block per mp and the Occupancy of each mp.

In fact it's dependant on your problem but you'll want to have your occupancy as high as possible, to avoid ressources from being wasted. On the other hand it is possible that your code is slowed down if the number of registers is restricted.

So there may be a point in not using all registers to avoid low occupancy but as I said it's a trade-off thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since many blocks can run on a single SM, you can hurt performance by allocating too many registers per thread. You are hardware limited on the SM - If your SM becomes "saturated" with 10 blocks (i.e. it never has to wait for blocks to complete a memory access since it has other work to do), but each block uses 1/5 of the registers at that SM, your utilization will be sub-par.

This also holds true for shared memory, which is limited (IIRC) to ~32k per SM. (+/- depending on your GPU/architecture)